# How to copy value and find the user in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, copy-paste, show-hide, cypress-component-test-runner

I try to copy the value from the filed (**First name*'**) then I want to find if in the list of users

But, when I type ('@value')to the serarch filed, the cypress put @value like text

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2azVO.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR91q.jpg)

`cy.contains('First name*').invoke('val').as('value')`

`cy.get('.search-wrap').first().click().type('@value','{enter}', {timeout:10000})`

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it like this:

```js
cy
  .contains('First name*')
  .invoke('val')
  .should(val => {
    cy
     .get('.search-wrap')
     .first()
     .click()
     .type(`${val}{enter}`, { timeout: 10000 });
  });
```